# Vertical list with complex viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have list of complex `UIViewControllers`. This list should be displayed in vertical form. I'm wondering how can I display them. I tried `UIPageViewController`, but it's showing just one child controller. I need to show them as many as can fit on screen (like `UITableView` or `UIScrollView`). I cannot use `UITableView`, because it doesn't support nested `UIViewControllers`. So do I have to use `UIScrollView` and implement own releasing mechanism for `child controllers` or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView:

in tableViewDelegate put

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    //calc cell height
    return height;
}
```

than in this method do like there:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:COMMON_CELL_IDENTIFIER];

    [self addChildViewController:viewControllers[indexPath.row]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:[viewControllers[indexPath.row] view]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This can work, but I'm not sure that child controllers will receive viewWillDisapper calls, generally that this model confirms Apple view controller containment rules

Comment: will receive, i ware use it